# Is the space complexity of this program really O(1)?

Tags: python, recursion, space-complexity

I encountered strange information today. I would say that the space complexity of this code is O(N). Each time the recursion happens, a new stack frame is made. And the number of recursive calls is proportional to the size of matrix (in this case 4). Am I right or maybe I'm not seeing something?

Btw the problem here is finding a celebrity (everybody knows them and they don't know anyone). We have the information required in the matrix and 1 means knowing, 0 means not knowing. For example person 0 doesn't know person 1 and knows person 2.

```
 # Person with 2 is celebrity
MATRIX = [[0, 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1, 0]]
 
 
def knows(a, b):
 
    return MATRIX[a][b]
 
# Returns -1 if a potential celebrity
# is not present. If present,
# returns id (value from 0 to n-1).
 
 
def findPotentialCelebrity(n):
 
    # Base case
    if (n == 0):
        return 0;
 
    # Find the celebrity with n-1
    # persons
    id_ = findPotentialCelebrity(n - 1)
 
    # If there are no celebrities
    if (id_ == -1):
        return n - 1
    # if the id knows the nth person
    # then the id cannot be a celebrity, but nth person
    # could be on
    elif knows(id_, n - 1):
          return n - 1
    # if the id knows the nth person
    # then the id cannot be a celebrity, but nth person
    # could be one
    elif knows(n - 1, id_):
          return id_
    # If there is no celebrity
    return - 1
 
# Returns -1 if celebrity
# is not present. If present,
# returns id (value from 0 to n-1).
# a wrapper over findCelebrity
def Celebrity(n):
 
    # Find the celebrity
    id_=findPotentialCelebrity(n)
 
    # Check if the celebrity found
    # is really the celebrity
    if (id_ == -1):
        return id_
    else:
        c1=0
        c2=0
 
        # Check the id is really the
        # celebrity
        for i in range(n):
            if (i != id_):
                c1 += knows(id_, i)
                c2 += knows(i, id_)
 
        # If the person is known to
        # everyone.
        if (c1 == 0 and c2 == n - 1):
            return id_
 
        return -1
 
# Driver code
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    n=4
    id_=Celebrity(n)
 
    if id_ == -1:
        print("No celebrity")
    else:
        print("Celebrity ID", id_)
```

Comment: You are not creating any new nee variables. I think you are confusing this with the time complexity.

Comment: *technically* the stack has a fixed maximum number of frames (in Python) so you could argue it's constant-space. Realistically, you're right though, it's linear. The time-complexity is probably more important here though.

Comment: In general I read that space complexity is proportional to the maximum depth of the recursion tree. That's why I'm confused. And you can't create recursion without any limits.  That's also because it would take up too much memory (you can get 'exceeded the max recursion limit error')